A new Android Studio project - "Plugin [id: 'com.android.application'] was not found in any of the following sources:"
Normally, there would be a list of sources below the error message, but there's empty on my log.
Some answers mentioned the google() repository, but it's been in the list.
Here is a portion of the build.gradle file:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"
    }
}


plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

The version of the JDK, Gradle and the Gradle Plugin are compatible.

The critical file here is your settings.gradle. What is in it?
